# Bug AutocompleteTextView width in dual pane Fragment UI

Tags: android, android-fragments, autocompletetextview

I'm currently facing a problem with my custom AutocompleteTextView, the dropdown is filling totally the screen but I only want it to fill one of my fragment width.

How can I solve this ?

Here a "beautiful" sketch of my view:

[image]

Thanks in advance :)